# CasperJS Not Rendering Google Recaptcha

Tags: phantomjs, recaptcha, casperjs

I'm trying to bypass a form protected by recaptcha using CasperJS. I'm using a third party service the provide the function to bypass recaptcha, however the captcha is never rendered.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
    },
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});
casper.start("https://website.com/protected/form");

casper.then(function() {
    casper.wait(5000, function() {
        casper.capture('/home/phantomjs/downloaders/screenshot-1.png');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Upon viewing the screenshot I see the recaptcha form is never rendered. I've tried adjusting the wait time to a longer period, no matter how long I wait it's never rendered.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the actual url of the page?

Comment: It's an adult website so I'm not sure that would be a good idea.

Comment: I switched to SlimerJS which uses Firefox and reCaptcha is rending fine now. Would still be interested in resolving this issue with CasperJS and/or PhantomJS as I am more familiar with both.